# Resolve all promises in Object

Tags: node.js

If you would have a function that would look smth like this:

```
async function foo() {
  const myString = 'some string';
  const myInt = 5;

  const promise1 = fetchData();  // An async function returning a promise
  const promise2 = fetchSomeOtherData(); // An async function returning a promise

  return {
    myString,
    myInt,
    promise1,
    promise2,
  }
}
```

And it would be important to me that `fetchData()` and `fetchSomeOtherData()` are executed at the same time (meaning adding await to both of these would not be a valid solution) is there a neat way to make the promises resolve when you call the function.
I am thinking of smth along the lines of `Promise.all()` just for an object that has SOME promises in it and not an array.
It is also important to me that my object keeps its structure as it is.
I am aware that there are some workarounds with `Promise.all()` where you cast the Object to an Array and reconstruct it afterwards but that wouldn't be as clean as I'd like it to be.

The way I would want to use the function and resolve the promises would be as follows:

```
const object = await foo();
```

and it should resolve both promises

Answer (score 1):

```js
async function foo() {
  const myString = 'some string';
  const myInt = 5;

  const promise1 = fetchData();
  const promise2 = fetchSomeOtherData();
  return {
    myString,
    myInt,
    promise1: await promise1,
    promise2: await promise2,
  }
}
```

A promise does not need `await` or `.then()` to start its execution. It starts to run once you create it and `await`/`.then()` are just two approaches to retrieve the execution result, but not to trigger the execution. Therefore when you run `fetchData()` and `fetchSomeOtherData()` they both start to execute immediately, and the second call does not wait for the first one.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. I forgot to mention that I would want to call the function in the manner of  "const object = await foo();" and that would not work in the given example

Comment: From what I can see, if you call the function with `await` and add two `awaits` in the returning object like I did in the answer, it will meet all your expectations. Promises are executed simultaneously when the function is called, and the object structure is exactly what you need. Tell me what do I miss in your requirements if it doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: oh adding an await in the return statement seems actually exactly like what I want and haven't tried yet. Thank you so much, I will give it a go!

Answer (score 1):

This would resolve *both promises* before returning the object:

```js
async function foo() {
  const [result1, result2] = await Promise.all([
    fetchData(),
    fetchSomeOtherData(),
  ])
  return {
    result1,
    result2,
  }
}
```